# Android emulator with acceleration and gyroscope simulation

Tags: android, debugging, eclipse

Is there an Android emulator that is compatible with [eclipse](/questions/tagged/eclipse) that can simulate acceleration and tilting of a mobile device?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try OpenIntents [SensorSimulator](https://code.google.com/p/openintents/wiki/SensorSimulator):

> **About the SensorSimulator**. The OpenIntents SensorSimulator lets you
>   simulate sensor data with the mouse in real time. Moreover, you can
>   simulate your battery level and your gps position too, using a telnet
>   connection.
>
> NEW! Now you can record a sequence with states from a real device.
>   Also you can use features like editing, saving, loading and playing
>   the scenario. It currently supports accelerometer, compass,
>   orientation, temperature, light, proximity, pressure, gravity, linear
>   acceleration, rotation vector and gyroscope sensors, where the
>   behavior can be customized through various settings. Here you can find
>   new features description.

[image]